# Terminal echos out environment variables when opening a new window

Tags: terminal, homebrew, ventura, zsh

When I open up a terminal (Apple Terminal, iTerm2, Hyper), the terminal echos out many environment variables and then shows the command prompt at the end, I'm not sure what has caused this. I installed PostgreSQL 15 this morning from Homebrew and added it to the PATH, but I haven't done anything else as far as I can find. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I'm using Zsh.

This is the contents of my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH=/Users/username/go/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin:$PATH
```

Here is what is displayed when I open a terminal:

```
COLORTERM=truecolor
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zWhwOCE2mL/org.xquartz:0
GPG_TTY=/dev/ttys000
HOME=/Users/username
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LOGNAME=username
MallocNanoZone=0
OLDPWD=/Users/username
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=undefined
PATH='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion Tech Preview.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/username/.local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/username/.cargo/bin:/Users/username/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts'
PWD=/Users/username
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.sFCwyS9nN4/Listeners
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=Hyper
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.4.1
TMPDIR=/var/folders/7p/r751n4gx24lcxvvsgrfq85lm0000gn/T/
USER=username
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=application.co.zeit.hyper.32895910.32896186
__CFBundleIdentifier=co.zeit.hyper
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:2
username@Mac-Studio ~ %
```

Comment: Look at the edit you made to change PATH, most likely something went wrong there.

Comment: @nohillside I've added the contents of my .zshrc file.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the output as well?

Comment: @Allan I have added the output.

Comment: That looks like the output of `printenv`.  Try the command `cd ~; grep -i “printenv” .z*` and post the output.

Comment: @Allan there is no output. But you got me thinking - I installed the python library python-dotenv at roughly the same time in a virtual environment which seems to be what the problem might be. I've deleted the whole environment but that hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Fixed it. I removed postgresql from my PATH and added it back in and it no longer prints out the env vars. I have no idea what went wrong but at least it is fixed now.

Comment: Post as an answer and ping me here in comments so I can upvote; plus it’ll help anyone else who runs into this.   I’m just happy you got it solved!

Comment: The .zshrc you posted, does not cause any output. If you experience this type of problem, first find the line which causes the problem (usually, running a login shell with `-x` turned on will show you the culprit, and its location), and then fix this.

Comment: BTW, I now notice that in the dump fo env vars you show, `PATH` has a faulty value, in that it contains single quotes. This means that you have messed it up somewhere. This must have happened **after** the PATH assignment you showed before. BTW, it is much easier and less errorprone in zsh to use the array `path` instead of the string `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it must have been a mistake on my part with the PATH. Also I'll look into zsh path. That sounds a lot better.